# Qt compiler flags order

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, compilation, clang

My goal is to get rid of some types of compiler warnings. I found out that I can do that by adding compiler flags in my .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-reorder
```

The problem is that they are added before flags that are generated by Qt build system. I've examined my compiler output:

> g++-4.2 -c -pipe -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-reorder -g -gdwarf-2 -arch
>   x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W
>   -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB

So as you can see *-Wall* goes after my flags and discards them. What should I do to add those flags after ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` but rather override `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON` with your own warnings:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-reorder
```