# How can I stop warnings about unused private fields?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, clang

While compiling a collection of files in a Qt project, I'm seeing lots of warnings similar to this one.

```
In file included from /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qevent.h:52:
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui/qmime.h:119:10: warning: private field 'type' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
    char type;
     ^
```

Per suggestions from various searches, I did add the entry

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-private-field

to the .pro file and confirmed that it shows up properly in compiler invocations but I'm still getting that warning.

I'm running Qt on a Mac with clang.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12253639/1041090), try

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-unused-private-field
```

It appears that the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON` flags are added to the compiler command line after `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`, and would re-enable that warning (because `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` contains `-Wall`).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds strange that you can't compile due to Qt library.
As I don't develop on Mac, what I would check is for supported Mac versions/compilers and how to compile on Mac. After that, if you fit requirements, I would report this as bug.

- [QT 4.8 Developing on Mac](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/developing-on-mac.html)
- [stackoverflow] [How to build qt 5 project on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493770/how-to-build-qt-5-project-on-mac)

Another approach (as already reported in this QT-Bug: [To #include  generates warnings](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29549)) is to include pragmas around warned headers.

```
 #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-private-field"
 #include <QtGui>
 #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wunused-private-field"
```

Comment: I didn't say I couldn't compile --- I just couldn't figure out how to eliminate a particular warning.

Comment: @David I misunderstood. It could help a pragma ignore.

Comment: There's something to be said for this approach so that the warnings will still be available for user code as opposed to library code though I hate to pollute my code with this stuff. However, since I've pulled down the entire source for Qt, I'm tempted to just remove the unused field myself!

Comment: gcc doesn't know about "-Wunused-private-field" and will warn with "unknown option after" this is a clang specific warning.

Comment: clang supports gcc pragmas, that's why the code indicates GCC. But that does not mean this specific warning exists in GCC, it was an example. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#pragma-gcc-diagnostic

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am not sure on points its bug of QT or not but I found one recent question on QT forum about same. I hope it is solved.

[Possible bug: qmime.h warning “char type is unused”](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/28100)

There is one more,
[Clang 4.2 warns about QMacMime unused private field "type"](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29377)

This may help you.

Comment: These aren't bugs as far as I know --- I assume they're legitimate warnings for the Qt code but it's just a pity that the Qt folks haven't ensured that their code doesn't have such things as unused fields and other things that would cause warnings.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a clang guy, but according to http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers you can use the `-isystem` flag with the directory in which those Qt headers are in, which will treat them as system includes and suppress warnings for them.

Comment: I tried adding    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem-prefix /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/ and 
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/
but that didn't help.